# How to know which facebook friend clicked my stream story?

Tags: authentication, facebook-graph-api, tracking, publish

Is there any way to know which facebook friend clicked on story published from my facebook app? Is possible with/without authorization?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can really suggest trying is REFERERS. PHP have a referer 'function' which can return the website that the user last came from.

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; ?>
```

Obviously the above is a VERY basic example. But once you have done that you can loop through and see where the user came from and then add the data into a database-table or whatever you want to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible due to privacy issues.  Facebook doesn't give any kind of info about what specific user viewed your profile, clicked your link, or anything of that nature.